# Why the temperature of the gas falls during its expansion which owes to the change in pressure only?

Tags: thermodynamics

It is said everywhere that when gas is allowed to expand enough slowly it temperature falls but the system keep adjusting its temperature at a single value by absorbing heat from reservoir continiously.

Text in both of the following photos suggest it.

From wikipedia:
[image]

From textbook:
[image]

Why does the temperature of the system (gas) fall when gas expands owing to the reduction of pressure?
What is its explanation at molecular level?

Answer (score 0):

First, macroscopically, when a volume of gas expands, it pushes against the gas surrounding it, and so does work against that surrounding gas. Thus, the expanding gas loses momentum and energy to its surrounding environment, which corresponds to a decrease in temperature (a la $\frac12kT$ energy per degree of freedom).

Microscopically, at the surface of the expanding gas, molecules inside the volume collide with molecules outside. And net energy is transferred out precisely corresponding to the fact that the volume expands. And that, in turn, corresponds to the fact that $T_{inside}>T_{outside}$, i.e., the inside molecular speed is, on average, greater than the outside speed, so average collisions transfer momentum (and energy) from inside to outside.

In comparison, suppose the volume of gas were expanding into a vacuum, so there are no collisions with outside molecules. That's called a throttling process. And guess what? -- no collisions, so no energy transfer outside the volume, and therefore no temperature change (at least not for an ideal gas).

Comment: Suppose gas is in a shape of sphere then the molecules which you call outsiders are molecules that form the surface of sphere. Is not it?

Comment: For the vacuum case, are you not ignoring black body radiation? Photons will be leaving too, depleting the kinetic energy of the atoms/molecules. In the case with the reservoir this is replaced.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Sure, everything happens at the surface, so to speak, more or less macroscopically a la Gauss's Theorem. And as (at)annav pointed out, energy is typically transferred from "inside" to "outside" by conduction, convection, and radiation. I only discussed conduction, since that seemed to be the mechanism you were fundamentally asking about.

Comment: @annav Yeah, I only discussed conduction since that seemed like the only mechanism relevant to what (at)SufyanNaeem was asking about.

Comment: @JohnForkosh first, tell me that in the first para, the gas which expands and the gas against which expansion occurs are same or not? And secondly, if the net energy transfer is outside (as you said) why would $T_{inside} > T_{outside}$? I think it should be $T_{outside} > T_{inside}$. shouldn't?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem (a)doesn't matter wheter the same or not. (b)$T_{inside}>T_{outside}$ means that the average (absolute value scalar) momentum $p_{inside}>p_{outside}$ due to that $\frac12kT$ stuff. So now just solve a two-body elastic collision problem and see which body gains momentum/energy as a result of the collision (you can do one-dimensional collisions since momentum is separately conserved for each degree of freedom). Note: if gases are the same inside/outside, then masses are the same, and you can just say $v_{inside}>v_{outside}$, which is what I wrote above without saying "same gas".

Comment: @JohnForkosh "..., when a volume of gas expands, it pushes against da gas surrounding it, and so does work against that surrounding gas. Thus ... to decrese in temperature...)." This is simple. But let us apply it to a volume of a gas enclsed in cylndr with a movable piston and the cylinder resting over reservoir. Suppose the only gas in the cylinder is our gas. It has a volume equal to cylinder's. When pressure is lowered, it expands by doing work on the piston and hence its $p$ and enrgy r trnsfrd to the piston and environment hence there is decrease in tmprutr. Is this explanation correct?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Yes, that description's pretty much correct. And what you're describing is pretty much an adiabatic expansion, as per the Carnot cycle, e.g., http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Thermodynamics/Thermodynamic_Cycles/Carnot_Cycle